# Why 1 dof test does not follow $\chi^2$ with 1 dof distribution?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, inference, chi-squared-test

This is related to a comment made in F. Harrell's Regression Modelling Strategies page 32 of Sec 2.6 on Multiple Degree of Freedom Tests of Association.

Consider $E(Y|X)=\beta_0+\beta_1 X+\beta_2 X'+\beta_3 X''+\beta_4 X'''$, the 5 knot restricted cubic spline where $X$ is the covariate.

Test $T$ of $H_0:\beta_1=\dots=\beta_4=0$ has 4 dof $\chi^2$ distribution by asymptotic maximal likelihood ratio test.

Consider $T'$ test $H'_0:\beta_2=\dots=\beta_4=0$.(i.e. Testing for linearity.) This test $T'$ will have 3 dof by asymptotic maximal likelihood ratio test.

Suppose $T'$ shows $\beta_2=\dots=\beta_4$ and $T$ shows $\beta_1=\dots=\beta_4=0$. However test of $H''_0: \beta_1=0$ is significant. We wish to test $\beta_1$ significance here.

"Had the test for linearity been borderline significant, it would not have been
warranted to drop these terms in order to test for a linear association. But
with the evidence for nonlinearity not very great, one could attempt to test
for association with 1 d.f. This however is not fully justified, because the 1
d.f. test statistic does not have a $\chi^2$ distribution with 1 d.f. since pretesting
was done."

Why $H''_0:\beta_1=0$ test does not follow 1 dof $\chi^2$ here? This is obviously nested model here. I could again apply asymptotic maximal likelihood ratio test which yields 1 dof $\chi^2$ .

Comment: The issue is not one of nested models, but of the "pretesting." This violates the assumptions needed to conclude the test statistic is well approximated by a $\chi^2(1)$ distribution.  The effect is difficult to quantify because it requires a model (!) of the "pretesting" procedure, which often is ill-defined.

Comment: @whuber Do you mean pretesting as model to set confidence level before conducting experiment? Or it is something else formally called pretesting procedure?

Comment: When you select the model based on the data, you have violated the assumptions of that model, which--among other things--are that the model was postulated independently of the data.  It's like the difference between shooting at an established target *versus* shooting at a wall and painting the target around your shots afterwards.

Comment: @whuber Thanks. I see.